# Concatenating values into column from multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing only duplicate "MainID" rows. 
 One MainID may have multiple secondary IDs (SecID). 
I want to concatenate the values of SecID if there is a common MainID, joined by ':' in SecID col.
 What is the best way of achieving this? 
Yes, I know this is not best practice, however it's the structure the software wants.
Need to keep the df structure and values in rest of the df. They will always match the other duplicated row. Only SecID will be different.

Current:

```
data={'MainID':['NHFPL0580','NHFPL0580','NHFPL0582','NHFPL0582'],'SecID':['G12345','G67890','G11223','G34455'], 'Other':['A','A','B','B']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
      MainID   SecID  Other
0  NHFPL0580  G12345  A
1  NHFPL0580  G67890  A
2  NHFPL0582  G11223  B
3  NHFPL0582  G34455  B
```

Intended Structure

```
MainID     SecID          Other 
NHFPL0580  G12345:G67890  A
NHFPL0582  G11223:G34455  B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby('MainID').apply(lambda x: ':'.join(x.SecID))
```

the above code returns a `pd.Series`, and you can convert it to a dataframe as @Guy suggested:

> You need .reset_index(name='SecID') if you want it back as DataFrame

The solution to the edited question:

```
df = df.groupby(['MainID', 'Other']).apply(lambda x: ':'.join(x.SecID)).reset_index(name='SecID')
```

You can then change the column order

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
df = df[[cols[i] for i in [0, 2, 1]]]
```

Comment: You need `.reset_index(name='SecID')` if you want it back as `DataFrame`.

Comment: I've added further information to the question. It seems to drop all of the other values in the DF. Is there a way to keep those values. They will always match the other duplicated row. Only SecID will be different.

Comment: @Adam I added a new solution

Comment: Really appreciate your help NuriTaş & @Guy . This is spot on.